# Differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac1{xy({x^2 \sin(y^2)+1})}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{xy({x^2 \sin(y^2)+1})}$

What would be a quick way to solve the above differential equation?

I have tried to rearrange the equation in the form of an exact differential but I am unable to do that. 
I get:

$2y\sin y^2 dy = \dfrac{2dx}{x^3} - \dfrac{2y}{x^2}dy$ which is not further simplifiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible Hint: See $$\frac{dy}{dx}=1/(\frac{dx}{dy})$$
It seems to me that this ,made your ODE to a Bernoulli's equation ODE.

Comment: You won by 6 seconds ! Cheers.

Comment: That is kind of you. :-))

Comment: Kind ? In what sense ? You won, that's it. $+1$ by the way.

Comment: +1, the simplest.

Comment: @paulplusx: Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Thanks. we did it almost at the same time analytically. :-) Indeed, I didn;t know your way.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

I think that it could be easier to consider $$\dfrac{dx}{dy} = {xy({x^2 \sin(y^2)+1})}$$ Now, define $x=\frac 1 {\sqrt z}$ to make
$$2 y \left(\sin \left(y^2\right)+z\right)+z'=0$$ For the homogeneous part $2yz+z'=0$, the solution is simple.

Comment: z'=$\frac{-2}{x^3}$ and z=$\frac{1}{x^2}$ Now how did you put $2y(sin(y^2)+z)+z'=0$

Comment: @DhamnekarWinod. $x=\frac 1 {\sqrt z}$ then $x'=-\frac{z'}{2 z^{\frac 32}}$. Replace and simplify.

Comment: Would you show me how to solve this differential equation with all the steps. Because I didn't understand your answer.How it can be a bernaulli equation ODE?